# bug in LTS 12.04 amd 64 iso file

Tags: 12.04, system-installation, iso, bug-reporting

I downloaded latest 64 bit version of ubuntu 12.04 LTS as an .iso file (ubuntu-12.04.4-desktop-amd64). and make my Pen Drive bootable using Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.5.2. when i try to install ubuntu on my PC, everything was OK until last moment when setup tried to install Grub2. the file was missing. Download link is http://ubuntu-releases.mirror.net.in/releases//precise/ubuntu-12.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso

Comment: The problem is likely with **your** downloaded copy of Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64-bit (or just possibly your local **mirror**). *I have used this **iso** file many times, since Feb-2014 when it was released, without any issues.*

Comment: When booting from it, you can select to verify. Do this...

Comment: david6, would you like to recommend any particular mirror?. My internet connection is slow and downloading such large file is not easy.

Comment: I verified, there was some in between message showing a file related to Grub2  "no such file..." and at last report, it shows error in three files.

Comment: hash check sum is correct

Answer (score 0):

This may have been caused by an incomplete download of your copy of the ISO file. 
To prevent this in the future, i suggest you to hash-check your download and compare it with the hash here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes

Check the iso-file with this program: http://download.cnet.com/HashCalc/3000-2250_4-10130770.html

Good luck!

Comment: hash check sum is correct.

Comment: Hmm okay then. There might be issues installing it then, which might not be a bug with the ISO, but with your computer? - I don't know what to suspect, but maybe drivers, etc. Or even the installer had a bug? Even though that this have worked perfectly well for other users :) however, Good luck with the problem :)